# Apple Music charges card or available balance?

Tags: itunes-store, apple-music

I am subscribed to Apple Music, and I also have a store credit from gift cards.

Will my monthly subscription subtract from my store credit or charge my credit card?

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, store credit will be used until it is gone, and then the credit card on file will be charged.